# A question about Bezout's theorem and general algebraic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have started reading basic texts of algebraic geometry and have come across a problem that I would like some help with.

A plane algebraic curve (PAC) of degree $d$ is the set of points over the complex numbers, whose coordinates satisfy a polynomial equation of degree $d$. For example, a general PAC of degree $2$ will be of the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$.

An equation for a PAC of degree $d$ is determined by $D(d)$ coefficients where $D(d)=\binom{d+2}{2}$. Here, $D$ is just the number of coefficients in a general polynomial equation of degree $d$ in $2$ variables. If I want a curve to contain a point $P$, that gives me a linear equation/constraint on the coefficients. So, if I specify $D(d)-1$ (which is $\approx d^2/2$) points, this determines a curve uniquely ($-1$ because scalar multiples of an equation specifies the same curve) containing these points. For example, for $d=2$, we have $\binom{2+2}{2}-1=5$ points determine a conic.

Bezout's theorem states that two distinct PACs $C_1$ and $C_2$ of degree $d$ meet at $d^2$ points (counting multiplicities).

However, from the third para, these $d^2$ points can at most specify one PAC uniquely. From Bezout, we have at least $C_1$ and $C_2$ which contain these points. Contradiction!

I had some ideas why my argument may not work but I don't know how to develop them. Firstly, perhaps the $d^2$ points from Bezout are such that they do not yield independent equations, so there is no uniqueness because the linear algebra argument in the third para fails.

Secondly, the $d^2$ points that I get from Bezout need to be distinct in order for my argument to work, but I thought one could assume that is what happens in a 'general' situation.

Comment: A first mistake that comes to mind is that Bezouts Theorem holds for projective curves and so there will probably be multiple intersections at "the point at infinity". This means that as you suggest in the general case the points are not distinct and so the initial process of determining the curves fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure of your argument as you guess is exactly because

> the $d^2$ points from Bezout are such that they do not yield independent equations, so there is no uniqueness because the linear algebra argument in the third para fails.

I think the simplest illustration is the case of plane cubics. Here there are ${3 + 2 \choose 2}=10$ coefficients, so 9 general points determine a unique cubic.

On the other hand, it is also true that 2 general cubics intersect in $3^2=9$ points. However, these points are definitely *not* general in the sense of the previous paragraph --- that is, they do not give linearly independent equations on coefficients of cubics. Indeed, any cubic that passes through 8 of the intersection points must also pass through the 9th (exercise!) so these 9 points really give 8 linear conditions.

---

For a starker illustration of the same point, you can look more closely at your dimension estimates: as you say, the family of plane curves of degree $d$ has dimension roughly $d^2/2$. So if you pick $d^2$ general points they should not lie on *any* curve of degree $d$. But clearly some sets of $d^2$ points do lie on a curve of degree $d$! The moral is just that when you pick a set of points with some special property ("intersection of 2 curves" or "lie on a curve of degree $d$") then you shouldn't really expect a statement that is stated for *general* sets of points to apply to that set.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the whole thing better now.